# Java 8 Lambda Stream forEach with two if-statements

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to refactoring some for-loops into lambda expressions, most of them are working fine, but I'm struggling with for-loops that contains two if-statements.

Code

```
        for (B2KTransactionDTO b2kTransactionDTO : result) {
            //Generate loyaltyMatchId based on transaction input
            String loyaltyMatchId = getLoyaltyMatchIdBasedOnTransactionDTO(b2kTransactionDTO);
            if (loyaltyMatchIdAmountMap.containsKey(loyaltyMatchId)) {
                BigDecimal cashback = loyaltyMatchIdAmountMap.get(loyaltyMatchId);
                b2kTransactionDTO.addLoyaltyPoints(cashback);
            }

            String loyaltyMatchInsuranceId = getLoyaltyMatchInsuranceIdBasedOnTransactionDTO(b2kTransactionDTO);
            if (loyaltyMatchInsuranceIdAmountMap.containsKey(loyaltyMatchInsuranceId)) {
                BigDecimal cashback = loyaltyMatchInsuranceIdAmountMap.get(loyaltyMatchInsuranceId);
                b2kTransactionDTO.addLoyaltyPoints(cashback);
            }
        }
```

I refactored this to the following code:

```
        result.forEach(b2kTransactionDTO -> {
            //Generate loyaltyMatchId based on transaction input
            String loyaltyMatchId = getLoyaltyMatchIdBasedOnTransactionDTO(b2kTransactionDTO);
            if (loyaltyMatchIdAmountMap.containsKey(loyaltyMatchId)) {
                BigDecimal cashback = loyaltyMatchIdAmountMap.get(loyaltyMatchId);
                b2kTransactionDTO.addLoyaltyPoints(cashback);
            }

            String loyaltyMatchInsuranceId = getLoyaltyMatchInsuranceIdBasedOnTransactionDTO(b2kTransactionDTO);
            if (loyaltyMatchInsuranceIdAmountMap.containsKey(loyaltyMatchInsuranceId)) {
                BigDecimal cashback = loyaltyMatchInsuranceIdAmountMap.get(loyaltyMatchInsuranceId);
                b2kTransactionDTO.addLoyaltyPoints(cashback);
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to even futher lambda-nize this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to lambdadize it? Labda's are marginally slower to start up/more memory intensive, and does not add much to readability of code. Or do you need the parralism to speed up the processing(which will only be relevant by large datasets)

Comment: You could transform this to _two_ independent `foreach` with added `map` and `filter` to "lambda-nize" it more... like `result.stream().map(...).filter(...).map(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: Also, your variable names are too long... consider putting those maps into a LoyaltyManager object, that handles the logic of matching id's and a returning cashbacks.

Comment: Maybe not lambdas, but you could probably refactor the two Hashmaps down to one and return some LoyaltyMatch object instead of two Strings.

Comment: I vote this as useless use of lambda.

Comment: @Tschallacka thank you for your feedback, I just start learning lambda expressions and was wondering if it was even possible, if that's not the case then I will revert the code back to the normal for-loops as I agree that the second code snippet doesn't make any sense as refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are looking for.

I would say, don't use lambda's here.

Lambda's can help you to utilise parralelism features of cpu's to speed up processing of large datasets.

In my experience it's not worth the hassle of utilising a lambda with smaller datasets(<10(0).000);

Keep your code readable and maintainable and pluggable.

Learn to make objects that handle purposes. Don't put all the things in one object and end up with veryLongVariableNamesThatDescribeAPurpose.

When long variable names occur it should be a signal to you that you can refactor that code into several objects that handle a single purpose.

If you really want to use lambda's try the following:
Seperate objects for value holders and processors and methods for seperate tasks, it will be easier in to utilise lambda's when needed because you can simply plug in the methods for the tasks required and pass on the value holder objects to get your desired results.

So, not the answer you're looking for, but this was too long really to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also should consider refactor your code because it looks like there's a lot of duplication between the *match* and *matchInsurance* stuff.

```
private static void addLoyaltyPoints(Collection<B2KTransactionDTO> result, Map<String, BigDecimal> ids, Function<B2KTransactionDTO, String> extractId)
{
    result.stream()
          .filter(b -> ids.containsKey(extractId.apply(b)))
          .forEach(b -> b.addLoyaltyPoints(ids.get(extractId.apply(b))));
}
```

Then the whole code you posted could become:

```
addLoyaltyPoints(result, loyaltyMatchIdAmountMap, Use::getLoyaltyMatchIdBasedOnTransactionDTO);
addLoyaltyPoints(result, loyaltyMatchInsuranceIdAmountMap, Use::getLoyaltyMatchInsuranceIdBasedOnTransactionDTO);
```

---

Edit: another version of `addLoyaltyPoints` (more concise, less expressive):

```
private static void addLoyaltyPoints(Collection<B2KTransactionDTO> result, Map<String, BigDecimal> ids, Function<B2KTransactionDTO, String> extractId)
{
    result.stream()
          .forEach(b -> b.addLoyaltyPoints(ids.getOrDefault(extractId.apply(b), new BigDecimal(0))));
}
```